# How to wrap texts in UITableviewcell on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

How to wrap texts in UITableViewcell on iPhone?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129502/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-uitableviewcell-without-a-custom-cell).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the lineBreakMode property on UITableViewCell?

**lineBreakMode**

The mode for for wrapping and truncating text in the cell. (Deprecated. Instead set the line-break mode attribute of the UILabel objects assigned to the textLabel and detailTextLabel properties.)

```
@property(nonatomic) UILineBreakMode lineBreakMode
```

**Discussion**

For further information, see the UILineBreakMode constants described in NSString UIKit Additions Reference. The default value is UILineBreakModeTailTruncation.

Answer (score 1):

You would also need to set the number of lines for the text label.

Example

```
[cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
```