# How do I create a text field or label that resizes based on how much text is in it?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I wrap text in a UITableViewCell without a custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129502/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-uitableviewcell-without-a-custom-cell)

I've seen at least one application that uses a grouped UITableView with a cell containing paragraphs of text, and the cell is taller or shorter based on the length of the text, but I don't quite get how this is done.

How does one, given a variable width font, figure out how high a UITextField or something needs to be in order to display all of the text contained in it without reducing the point size of the font?

Answer (score 1):

See Apple's documentation about [`NSString` additions for the iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to read about which methods to use to calculate these metrics.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not used to the whole Category pattern used in Objective-C. I understand how it works and what the point is, but I'm just so used to being able to look up the docs for `NSString` and find ALL of the supported methods. So I keep finding methods like `awakeFromNib` that are defined as NSObject methods, and I'm basically like "WTF? I thought I read the docs on NSObject already?" I wish there were a good way I could look up all of the methods for a given class like NSString defined by anything that defines a category in say Cocoa Touch or something.

Comment: Apple added a few category additions for `NSString` and `UITableView` to help make them easier to use on the iPhone. You can also make your own category additions, to make these and other classes more useful. Categories are a really awesome design pattern for Objective-C and I definitely recommend learning about them. That said, the one thing I have learned from my limited amount of time working with Cocoa is that the best docs are the header files themselves, as opposed to Apple's official documentation.