# Wrap words in uitableview, iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, word-wrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I wrap text in a UITableViewCell without a custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129502/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-uitableviewcell-without-a-custom-cell)

I am creating an rss feed application. As a sample i have downloaded apples rss feed, but the problem with it is that the words in the table cells are not wrapped. As the contents are of very lengthy, the users may not be able to read the full text from the table unless by going to that link. Instead, I need to display that in 2 or 3 lines, otherwise saying, need to use word wrap in the tables. How to implement that? pls reply

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129502/