# textLabel in a UITableViewCell two+ lines (no cutoff)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, textlabel

I have a RSS feed reader app which each cell collets a title from an element in an XML from RSS feed apple website. Now the titles are very long so what I wanted to do was increase the size of the each cell using:

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return 80;
  }
```

to make the title come in two or more lines and spread out but the text continues to go on straight and cut off. How can i fix this?

Comment: IS THERE SOMETHING WRONG WITH THIS QUESTION THAT I CAN IMPROVE???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as setting the `numberOfLines` property on the UILabel and the `lineBreakMode` property to allow the `UILabel` to auto-support multiple lines of text.

Comment: I corrected my reply, thanks for pointing this out. I was thinking about java swing JLabels.

Comment: And a down turns to an up...!

Answer (score 1):

You only set the cell height, but the UILabel is still a single line label. To change that see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129502/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-uitableviewcell-without-a-custom-cell).