# Autoresize on UITableViewCell not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129502/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-uitableviewcell-without-a-custom-cell) popular approach for autoresizing content in UITableViewCell. And it's not working.
All I get is this:

[image]

My app is a universal app and I'm using iOS 5 with a storyboard. Here's my code for .h file:

```
@interface SecondMasterViewController : UITableViewController
```

And for these two methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.mainCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *myAwesomeCellImage;
    myAwesomeCellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                           cell.textLabel.text,@".png"]];
    cell.imageView.image = myAwesomeCellImage;

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = @"Go get some text for your cell.";
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 20;
}
```

What have I done wrong? I've tried different approaches and all of them don't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 is getting called?

Comment: Well, I've just set a breakpoint and yes, it is being called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use the literal string `@"Go get some text for your cell."` in your `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`? I think you're supposed to replace that with the actual text of the cell, so you can size it out and see how tall the cell needs to be. Try replacing that string with `[self.mainCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` (what you set for your cell text) and see if it helps.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot for this easy solution