# UITableViewCell multi line section headers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I would like to make the text labels in the default section headers of an UITableView (UITableViewStylePlain) to have multiple line. For the cells this can be easily achieved as described in [How do I wrap text in a UITableViewCell without a custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129502/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-uitableviewcell-without-a-custom-cell). How can I do the same for the default section headers? If there is no way to do this, how can I create an header view in tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: that looks identical to the default header?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 6 introduced a new class called [UITableViewHeaderFooterView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewHeaderFooterView_class/Reference/Reference.html) which looks just like the default header (and also has a detail text label). I've not tried it, but you might be able to use this as a customer header view and set the `textLabel` properties in the same way as in the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I also found this method. Unfortunately my app needs to support also iOS 5.x devices.